# USB webcam no output

Tags: usb, webcam, monterey

I got a pretty weird problem with my m1 Macbook air (Monterey). The USB webcam sometimes outputs a black screen on all applications.

1. The webcam doesn't have any cover.
2. The webcam is plugged in a usb 3.0 hub, which is plugged in a usb-c dongle, which is connected to my macbook. Pulling out and re-plug in the dongle, the hub, as well as the camera won't solve the problem.
3. Turning the macbook off and back on is a hit or miss: sometimes it can fix it, other times it can't.
4. Entering safe mode can fix the problem. Rebooting into the normal mode after entering safe mode will keep the problem solved. But it will come back randomly.
5. The camera works perfectly fine on another windows laptop.
6. Ok, I just found this out: it seems like plugging in the webcam while the internal camera is in use can cause this problem. The internal camera always works fine.
7. Never had this problem on Big Sur. It's probably a Monterey bug.

Edit:

1. Seems like the it's the Plug-n-Play part of the function is broken. The camera has to be connected from boot, and will fail after it's unplugged and plugged back in when Mac is turned on.

What's my next step? Anyone having a similar problem?

Comment: This is still an issue for me. Could not fix it yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a direct USB-C to USB-A, try using that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on M1 laptop, and the Logitech B525 completely stopped working after the Monterey upgrade.

Mysteriously, I found that installing ManyCam fixed all my webcam problems (apps needed be restarted to see the camera). I can now unplug and plug it again, and all the apps sees it. Uninstalling ManyCam reintroduces the problem. I never had ManyCam installed before having that problem, so it wasn't causing the problem to begin with.

While using the camera, I can see a process called `ManyCamVideoDeviceAgent` (intel) that disappears when stop using the camera. I guess it is doing something right.